# Misconfiguration of web service (WCF) causing error when consumed by an application

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm learning WCF and I'm trying to test an application locally. However, I'm encountering the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'net.tcp://xxx/Services/xx/xx.svc' could not be activated...

My attempts to solve this has been to add `https` with `net.tcp` in the configuration of the application in IIS. I also tried to apply the suggestions from this post without success: [What are the reasons that cause ServiceActivationException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338729/what-are-the-reasons-that-cause-serviceactivationexception).

My web configuration is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="connectionStringFinish" value="DAT;" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="xs.xs">
                <endpoint 
                    address=""
                    binding="netTcpBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="mynetTcpBinding"
                    contract="xs.Ixs"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
            <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment 
                aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"    
                multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging 
                    maxSizeOfMessageToLog="1000000" 
                    logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
                    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
                    logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
                    maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
        </diagnostics>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm looking for an answer that no only solves the problem, but that may provide references and/or explanation for what I did wrong in the configuration. Thank you.

~CH

Comment: Your binding configuration should be corrected

Comment: Make sure you have installed WCF non-HTTP activation components. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053(v=vs.110).aspx)